# How to center 3 imgs side by side?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to center 3 social-media icons side by side. but couldn't figure out how to do it.

[image]

```
<div class="maintext flipInX animated">

   <div class="socials wow bounce animated" data-wow-delay="1s">
     <a href="www.facebook.com">  <img src="http://s33.postimg.org/yitnj0vbz/fblogo.png"/></a>
     <a href="www.github.com"> <img src="http://s33.postimg.org/r7peysh3z/github.png"/></a>
     <a href="www.linkedin.com"> <img src="http://s33.postimg.org/lq7vvi8wv/linkedin_3_32.png"/></a>
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q23gbkdr/)

Make the `<a>` inside the `.socials` div `inline-block` element which gives it a property as that of text. And, then add `text-align:center` to the parent, ie the `.socials` div.

Add the below given CSS to make it centered

```
.socials{
    text-align:center;
}
.socials a{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

**UPDATE**

As, @LGSon mentioned in his comment,

> An inline element does not need to be set to `inline-block` to center
>   itself when the parent has `text-align: center`

you just need to add the below given CSS to make it centered.

```
.socials{
        text-align:center;
}
```

But, please do keep in mind that you have to set the display of any block level elements to `inline-block` if it needs to be centered using the above said method.

Comment: Saying `display:inline-block;` is needed to make them center is wrong, hence my down vote.

Comment: An inline element does not need to be set to `inline-block` to center itself when the parent has `text-align: center`, as you can see in my answer

Comment: Yes..got it..But I was giving a solution in general, that would help him and others in the future.. @LGSon

Comment: Telling users they need to set the anchor to `display: inline-block` for `text-align: center` work is not helping, it is to misguide them.

Comment: @LGSon your point is very much clear..thanks for pointing out..updated the answer..

Comment: Thankyou..@LGSon.. :) Happy coding.. :) :)

Comment: You're welcome ... and to say _..you have to set the display of any block level elements to `inline-block` if it needs to be centered using the above said method_ is as well wrong, setting it to `inline` will also center it.

Comment: Yeah..ofcourse..i was just mentioning just one way of doing it..@LGSon

Answer (score 2):

Use `text-align: center`

```css
.socials {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="maintext flipInX animated">

   <div class="socials wow bounce animated" data-wow-delay="1s">
     <a href="www.facebook.com">  <img src="http://placehold.it/50"/></a>
     <a href="www.github.com"> <img src="http://placehold.it/45"/></a>
     <a href="www.linkedin.com"> <img src="http://placehold.it/50"/></a>
   </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox is great for centering things both horizontally and vertically:

```css
img { height:40px; width:40px; background-color:gray }

.socials { 
  display: flex;
  justify-content:center;
}
.socials img {
  flex: 1 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="maintext flipInX animated">

   <div class="socials wow bounce animated" data-wow-delay="1s">
     <a href="www.facebook.com">  <img /></a>
     <a href="www.github.com"> <img /></a>
     <a href="www.linkedin.com"> <img /></a>
   </div>

</div>
```